# UIButton with image centered over text misaligns for some images

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uibutton

I'm currently trying to get a set of buttons (subclass of UIButton) with custom icons and text to conform to a pattern where the icon is centered above the text, and both together are centered horizontally and vertically inside the button.

```
    CGSize textSize = [[self titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] sizeWithFont:self.titleLabel.font 
                                                                     forWidth:self.frame.size.width 
                                                                lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    [self setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
    [self setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];
    [self setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, textSize.height + 10, 0)];
    [self setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.imageView.frame.size.height + 10, 
                                              -self.imageView.frame.size.width, 
                                              0, 0)];
```

For most of the icon/text combinations, this works. However, for a few, everything gets wonky.  The text always seems to stay aligned in the center, but the icons tend to get pushed off to the left, sometimes at zero(x), sometimes somewhere between zero and center.

The icons are mostly of different sizes, but all fit nicely within the buttons with plenty of room to spare for the text. If I use the text for one of the misaligned buttons in a button that does align nicely, it will misalign.  If text from an aligned button goes with an icon from a misaligned one, it will usually align, but not always. It seems to be some combination of the icon size and text size, but I can't see anything wrong with any of them.

Is there a more proper way of setting these insets to make this work?

I've been tweaking and playing with this for hours, and I cannot for the life of me figure out what's going on.  Here are the relevant frames from each button:

```
Image: {{24, 35}, {29, 25}}
Title: {{11, 63}, {55, 28}}
inSelf: {{0, 0}, {78, 120}} => Good

Image: {{23, 36}, {32, 23}}
Title: {{5, 62}, {67, 28}}
inSelf: {{0, 0}, {78, 120}} => Good

Image: {{21, 36}, {35, 23}}
Title: {{15, 62}, {48, 28}}
inSelf: {{0, 0}, {78, 120}} => Good

Image: {{6, 35}, {28, 25}}
Title: {{10, 63}, {57, 28}}
inSelf: {{0, 0}, {78, 120}} => Bad

Image: {{0, 38}, {29, 20}}
Title: {{12, 61}, {53, 28}}
inSelf: {{0, 0}, {78, 120}} => Bad
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue trying to work with a custom tab bar (TBKit). Any luck you found something?